# Leverage Browser caching for woff2 after appling Cloudflare to my WordPress website

Tags: nginx, wordpress, google, cloudflare, font

I have a WordPress website running on an Nginx webserver on Ubuntu. The site basically runs fine, quite fast, no significant problems.

I do get this error in a [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) test. It started the moment after I applied Cloudflare to my domain:

> ### Leverage browser caching
>
> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in
>   the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load
>   previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the
>   network. Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable
>
> **resources**:
>   https://example.com/…/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 (4
>   hours)

I thought I might need to add `woff2` to my Nginx location block dealing with resource expiration:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|woff2|pdf)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

Note the `woff2` after the `woff`. I then restarted the server but no significant change was seen.

I do wonder, mostly out of curiosity, why applying Cloudflare caused the appearance of this Google Pagespeed Insights error.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Cloudflare cache?

Comment: Yes --- my problem happens **after** I tried it.